# Transforming array from 'long' data format to 'wide' format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to transform data I'm getting from an API to match the format of a table that I'd like to display to show revenue into the future. I have the following array:

```
const data = [{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Dwight',
        Name: 'A',
        Month: 'Oct',
        Revenue: 2
      },{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Dwight',
        Name: 'A',
        Month: 'Nov',
        Revenue: 3
      },{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Dwight',
        Name: 'B',
        Month: 'Dec',
        Revenue: 1
      },{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Andy',
        Name: 'B',
        Month: 'Nov',
        Revenue: 4
      }]
```

I would like to be able to transform the array to look like the following:

```
const data2 = [{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Dwight',
        Name: 'A',
        Oct: 2,
        Nov: 3,
        Dec: 0
      },{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Dwight',
        Name: 'B',
        Oct: 0,
        Nov: 0,
        Dec: 1
      },{
        director: 'Michael',
        lead: 'Jim',
        mgr: 'Andy',
        Name: 'B',
        Oct: 0,
        Nov: 4,
        Dec: 0
      }]
```

Essentially, I would like to group the data by the first few properties and then summarize the revenue by month for the given group.

I haven't been able to find a viable solution. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: would there be a situation where you would list a name and month more than once?

Comment: @zfrisch. No, I don't think that would ever be expected. Any thoughts on how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of Array reduce and a map can do it

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'A',
  Month: 'Oct',
  Revenue: 2
},{
  name: 'A',
  Month: 'Nov',
  Revenue: 3
},{
  name: 'B',
  Month: 'Dec',
  Revenue: 1
}];
const months = data.reduce((acc, {Month})=> (acc[Month] = 0, acc), {});
const result = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, {name, Month, Revenue}) => {
  acc[name] = acc[name] || {};
  acc[name][Month] = Revenue;
  return acc;
}, {})).map(([name, obj]) => ({name, ...months, ...obj}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've learned that I need it to be a bit more in depth however. Could you take a look at my updated question and then extend your answer? I'd greatly appreciate any further insights you have.

Comment: Well, now this answer looks like its for a different question - the fact that you don't have a single key on the input that maps to a record on the output complicates the code quite a bit - I'll just delete the answer